# Fill gaps in binary leaf image occured from segmentation preserving leaf teeth shape

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, image-morphology

after leaf segmentation i got the following binary image: 
[image]
Is there a way to fill the gaps caused by the similiarity of the veins with the background? I've tried to use imclose, or imdilate etc but it affects teeth shape. I can't find out how to fill these gaps without affecting teeth shape.

Comment: The right solution might be changing how you segment the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try `bwfill(I, 'hols')`, with out without `imclose`:

```
I = imbinarize(rgb2gray(imread('leaf.jpg')));
I = I(3:end-4, 1:end-8); %Remove white frame
J = imclose(I, ones(2)); %Minor affect the teeth shape (result looks better with imclose).
K = bwfill(J, 'hols'); %Fill the black hols
```

Result:
[image]

---

In case you want to fill the "vein gaps", you can try the following approach:

```
I = imbinarize(rgb2gray(imread('leaf.jpg')));
I = I(3:end-4, 1:end-8); %Remove white frame
I = bwfill(I, 'hols'); %Fill small black hols.
J = imerode(imdilate(I, strel('disk',5)), strel('disk',10)); %Dilate with radius 5 and erode with 10
T = (I == 0) & (J == 1); %Create mask with 1 where I is black and J is white "vein mask".
K = I;
K(T) = 1; %Fill "vein mask" in I with white.
K = bwfill(K, 'hols'); %Fill small black hols (fill tiny holds left).
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the vein gaps remain there

Comment: @AsukaMatseli: I know what you mean with vein gaps, but it might be good if you could indicate those in an image uploaded to your question so it's clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @AsukaMatseli I tried filling the vein gaps. Is that what you have meant?